# How to print a 1x2 list from 2 separate lists?

Tags: python, list, parsing

I need to print 2 entries from list 2 for every one entry in list 1

So say

```
ll = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"
l2 = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i"
```

I need to print

```
1 a b
2 c d
3 d e
4 f g
5 h i
```

and so on

I can do

```
for i,j in zip(matches,matches2):
    print (i,j)
```

but this just prints

```
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 d
```

but i can't work out how to print 2 entries from matches2 for every 1 entry in matches

Comment: Why do you have `d` twice in `1 a b
2 c d
3 d e
` ... ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an iterator from `matches2` so that it can be extracted twice for each iteration with `zip`:

```
iter2 = iter(matches2)

for i, j, k in zip(matches, iter2, iter2):
    print(i, j, k)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your first example strings you can do something like this:

```
ll = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9".split(',')
l2 = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i".split(',')

for i in range(0,len(ll)):
    j=i*2
    if j+1<len(l2):
        print(ll[i],l2[j],l2[j+1])
```